# Copying Data From S3 to Redshift, Same Region but I get error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

I am running the COPY command to copy data from S3 to a staging table in Redshift using the following command.

```
cur.execute("copy my_table from '{}' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key=' delimiter ',' csv region 'eu-west-1';".format(
        s3_bucket_uri))
```

The issue is I get the following error

```
 S3ServiceException:The S3 bucket addressed by the query is in a different region from this cluster.
```

Now the problem is that this makes no sense since my bucket which I am fetching the files from in in the same region as the cluster I am loading it to.

See images below.

[image: S3 Bucket]

[image: Redshift Cluster]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the region option.  It is thinking is is a cross region copy but it is in the same region.  Just don't use that option.